# Windows phone Lumia 929 Upgraded from 8.x to 10 lost contacts

Tags: windows-10-mobile, contacts

I just update my Windows phone Lumia 929 to Windows 10 and lost contacts.  I have tried everything that I have read.  I tried to revert to windows 8 with the same result.  I need help!

Comment: Have you logged in with the same MS account as before? Were the contacts saved to your MS account? Can you see the contacts if you log in at https://people.live.com?

Comment: I may have saved them to Verizon Backup Assistant Plus, but I stopped service with Verizon around the day I upgraded to Windows 10 mobile, so perhaps it closed my Verizon account.  I was hoping the phone saves contacts somewhere too?

Comment: Well, it *should* save them to your Microsoft account. Again, try checking https://people.live.com.